# Pandas Datetime column to Excel Serial TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, excel, numpy

I have a column in my dataframe that has a bunch of dates with hours and minutes, I am trying to replace it or create a new one with the serial format of excel and have it as float to do some computations.

I tried many things and still can't get this to work. It doesn't matter what I try I keep getting errors. The source csv from where I am loading has column named df['dates'] and it looks like this:

```
0       2022-02-23 09:30:00-05:00
1       2022-02-23 09:45:00-05:00
2       2022-02-23 10:00:00-05:00
3       2022-02-23 10:15:00-05:00
4       2022-02-23 10:30:00-05:00
                  ...            
7912    2023-04-25 10:45:00-04:00
7913    2023-04-25 11:00:00-04:00
7914    2023-04-25 11:15:00-04:00
7915    2023-04-25 11:30:00-04:00
7916    2023-04-25 11:45:00-04:00
```

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

# convert datetime column to excel serial number format
excel_serial_dates = pd.to_datetime("1900-01-01") + pd.to_timedelta(df['dates'] - pd.Timestamp("1899-12-30"), unit='D')
df['excel_serial'] = pd.Series([x.to_pydatetime().timestamp() / 86400 + 25569 for x in excel_serial_dates])

# convert excel serial number column to float
df['excel_serial'] = df['excel_serial'].astype(float)
```

However it returns the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timestamp'
```

Any suggestions? I know there has to be a simple way to do this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so finally I realized that when I was loading the file from the CSV Python was recognizing the date column as an object which kept on throwing everything off. Here is how I solved it:

```
# Convert the 'datetime_column' to Pandas datetime format with UTC timezone
df['datetime_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], utc=True)


# Convert timezone-aware datetime values to UTC timezone
df['datetime_column'] = df['datetime_column'].dt.tz_convert('UTC')

# Convert the Pandas datetime format to Excel serial format
excel_serial = (df['datetime_column'] - pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01', tz='UTC')) / pd.Timedelta('1 day')
excel_serial += ((df['datetime_column'].dt.hour * 3600 + df['datetime_column'].dt.minute * 60
                  + df['datetime_column'].dt.second) / 86400)

# Convert the resulting values to floats
excel_serial = excel_serial.astype('float64')

# Replace the original column with the transformed values
df['datetime_column'] = excel_serial
df
```

If anybody has a more Pythonic way to do this, would love to see it! Many thanks!